# Why syncfusions DomainUpDown control not visible in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, syncfusion

When i add an updown control its working

```
<syncfusion:UpDown Grid.Column="1">
```

But when i add DomainUpDown control its not visible

```
<syncfusion:DomainUpDown Grid.Column="1"></syncfusion:DomainUpDown>
```

I know there is a DomainUpDown control because it was showing in the intellisense.

I have tried searching similar issues but cant see none.

Comment: I was able to replicate your issue when using the Nuget manager to reference the Syncfusion controls. (.NET Core) . I haven't found a fix. When I created a brand new Syncfusion WPF project using the local install directory I had no issues.  I'm assuming it's an issue with the versioning.  Try a new project and note the versions of the assemblies referenced. I'm sure it has something to do with versioning on the references.

Answer (score 0):

We suggest you use SfDomainUpDown instead of DomainUpDown. Please find the Code Snippet and UG reference for the same,

Code Snippet:

```
<syncfusion:SfDomainUpDown Width="100" Height="30" Value="10" />
```

UG: https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/domain-updown/getting-started